# Blank Page Issue: PHP Web Application Not Displaying "Add Vendor" Page

Tags: php

Question:

I'm developing a PHP web application, and I've encountered a peculiar issue. I have a menu structure with various links, each leading to different functionalities of the application. However, when I click on the "Add Vendor" link, the page goes completely blank. The other pages load perfectly as expected. Here are the details:

Scenario:

The web application is running on a local development server.
The menu is created using HTML and PHP includes to load specific content.
Other menu links work fine, but the "Add Vendor" link results in a blank page.

Code:

The PHP code for handling the "Add Vendor" page is located in add_vendor.php. This file is included via PHP's include statement within the main page (index.php) when the "Add Vendor" link is clicked.

Here's how the "Add Vendor" page (add_vendor.php) is structured:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['logged']) != true) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    die();
}
?>
<h1 style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5%;">Add Vendor</h1>
<div class="form-container">
    <form method="post" action="index.php?add_vendor" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Vendor Details</legend>
            <ul class="form-flex-outer">
                <!-- Form fields go here -->
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['add_vendor'])) {
    $vendor_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['vendor_name']);
    $vendor_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['vendor_email']);
    $vendor_contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['vendor_contact']);

    $insert_vendor = "INSERT INTO vendor (contact_name, email, phone_no) VALUES ('$vendor_name', '$vendor_email', '$vendor_contact')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $insert_vendor)) {
        echo "Vendor added successfully!";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
?>
```

When I click on the "Add Vendor" link, I want it to display the `add_vendor.php` page. However, it currently doesn't work as expected, and the page appears blank. Here's the relevant part of my `index.php` code:

```
<li class="has-children bookmarks">
    <a href="#0">Vendors</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?view_all_vendor">View All Vendors</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?add_vendor">Add Vendor</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I've created an "add_vendor.php" page, but it doesn't display as expected when I click the link. What could be the issue here, and how can I make it work properly so that clicking the "Add Vendor" link displays the "add_vendor.php" page?

Comment: `$conn` isn't defined, and you don't have anything lines to include a connection script.

Comment: Blank pages can be a sign that there is an error in your PHP script, check the network section of your developper tools, maybe you have the error there (in the response section) or an error code (like 500 probably), and you should add it to the question. Something I noticed: you use `$conn` but it is not defined in your code

Comment: A white page usually means a 500 Internal Server Error. A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Smething else that can go wrong, you say that this code is added to another page via `include`. Be careful about the `header()` function, it should never be used after you have started to output something (even a space before the `<?php` tag can cause this error)

Comment: Turn on error reporting. Check the error logs. If you find some error, add it to the question. Also, look at the network tab and see what's being received. Finally, look at the server logs as well. A good test is to temporarily replace your script for Add Vendor with a simple `echo "foo";` and see whether it appears when you load the page. If so, then something's wrong in your script. If not, then something's wrong with your server or link.

Comment: How does `index.php?add_vendor` invoke `add_vendor.php`? Have you got some other code for doing that? Have you verified that bit of the code is doing what it's supposed to? There isn't enough info here for us even to be certain we've got a [mre] of the issue in front of us.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data. mysqli_real_escape_string is obsolete and doesn't guard against everything.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: And please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident. In a live environment you should always log all PHP errors to a file.